# HighCharts - Two datasets and two y-axis

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I would like to create a chart that should look something like this:[image]

As you can see there are two different datasets. Furthermore, I know the mapping of the left values to the right values.

The problem is that as soon as I enter two datasets in my chart, the mapping of the values does not work anymore. Is there any possibility in highcharts that I can specify the mapping of two different units?

Thanks,

enne

Edit: This is my current approach: jsfiddle.net/enne87/7r4roq0e/2

Comment: Yes.  Make a fiddle example so we can see how you're trying to do it.

Comment: Good idea thanks, here is one approach with two datasets: http://jsfiddle.net/enne87/7r4roq0e/

Comment: Right now, where the problem is, what kind of mapping you have, and how does your source data looks like?

Comment: Right now I achieved to create something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/enne87/7r4roq0e/2/
Anyway, as you can see in this example, the two data-sets have to contain the exact same data-values. As soon as I change the data values in one of the sets, it does not work anymore.

Comment: Its unclear what doesnt work, http://jsfiddle.net/7r4roq0e/5/ works well. So replicate what is incorrect.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/7r4roq0e/6/ I changed the data of the second data-set slightly. Now for example, 4k is mapped to 23P. But 4k should always be mapped to 60P.